# Why can't the parts of "able to" and "capable of" be switched?

Tags: etymology, adjectives

Why are "able to [verb]" and "capable of [gerund]" both perfectly valid English, but "capable to [verb]" sounds slightly off and "able of [gerund]" sounds entirely wrong? What's the etymological reason?

Comment: @Alan Carmack These are actually adjectives, not verbs. But I like everything else you had to say. I agree that the prepositions which adjectives take do seem to be unpredictable. Maybe it has to do with euphony—whatever sounds nice.

Comment: @ktm5124 - Who is Alan Carmack? I'm sorry but their comment isn't loading for me. If you meant me, I meant the parts in brackets to be places where you could substitute in any verb of your choice, but I can see how that would be confusing. Sorry about that.

Comment: I was actually talking to someone else. I think the comment I was responding to got deleted. The notation in your question was very clear and I understood what you were talking about.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry, I should've realized. But thanks! 

& I would've liked to read that comment too, from what you said in your response it sounded interesting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've made a false syntactic dichotomy between infinitives and gerunds as complements to the adjectives *able* and *capable*. The distinction is between infinitives and prepositional phrases. *Able* can take an *infinitive*, but not a *prepositional phrase*:

> **[1a]**   I am **able** *to paint*.
>   **[1b]** *I am **able** *of anything*.

The object of a preposition could, of course, be a gerund:

> **[1c]** *I am **able** *of painting*.

But what's not licensed is the prepositional phrase, not the gerund as the object of the preposition.

The reverse is true of *capable*, which can't take an infinitive, but instead requires a prepositional phrase:

> **[2a]** *I am **capable** *to paint*.
>   **[2b]**   I am **capable** *of anything*.

Both words are derived from Old French cognates, but etymology won't provide an answer. Per the *OED*, both words in their history in the language have taken as complements both infinitives and prepositional phrases with *of* and *for*. For instance, *capable to hold* once meant "having the capacity to hold", as of a ship. This usage became obsolete and with it the capability (as it were) of *capable* to take an infinitive. It's impossible to say what drove the idiom to its modern state.

Answer (score 0):

Some adjectives are capable of taking the *to*-infinitive, but others aren't. *Able* is one of the adjectives that can, but not *capable*.

On the other hand, some adjectives can be combined with a preposition followed by a gerund. I don't know if *able* has any such combinations. But *capable* works well with *of* and *in*.

Here's a word that fits both constructions: anxious.
A person can be anxious to go to work, as well as anxious about returning home. See how this sentence uses both constructions?

[Here's a list](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/adjective_infinitive_list.htm) of adjectives which take the *to*-infinitive, and [here's a list](http://www.englishpage.com/gerunds/adjective_prep_gerund_list.htm) of adjective+preposition+gerund combinations.