# Passive voice sentence

Tags: idioms, passive-voice, syntactic-analysis, predicate-frames

I saw an idiom in the Merriam-Webster Dictionary, [be 
had](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/be%20had), 
defined there as:

> to be tricked or fooled by someone

And I saw its usage like this

> She doesn’t want to buy a used car because she’s worried about *being
>   had* by a dishonest salesman.

Why is it *being had* instead of *be had*?

- If the latter part (after *because*) is a noncontinuous present-tense 
  passive, then why is *being* being used?
- If it is a continuous
  present-tense passive, then why is *being* used before *had* and not before
  *worried*, and where has *be* in *be had* gone (if *being* in *being had* 
  is there because of the tense)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't the parts of "able to" and "capable of" be switched?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/360643/why-cant-the-parts-of-able-to-and-capable-of-be-switched). 'Worried about', like 'capable of', takes an _ing_-form not an infinitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you've got there is that you've not taking into account the part of the idiom that is the verb '**to be**'.

It is possible for the lady **to be had** by a used car salesman.

If it has already happened, she **has been had** by said salesman.

If it is in the future, it is *possible* that she **will be had**, but it is not definitive that she will be, so she is concerned about the likelihood of **being had** at that future point in time.

The statement could also exist in the form:

> She doesn't want to buy a used car because she's worried that she **may be had** by a dishonest salesman.

Answer (score 2):

Because like most prepositions, *about* in *to be worried about* cannot take a verb in the infinitive as its complement, only a verb inflected into the gerund form. When you *are worried about something*, you cannot swap an infinitive in for *something*, only a gerund.

If I were you, I wouldn't be worrying about tense here, because nonfinite verbs (read: infinitives, gerunds, participles) by definition have no tense.

And for that matter, just like the deponent verb *to be born*, the verb *to be had* may not be best analysed as a passive. After all, if *“She was had by the salesman”* is the passive, what then is the active corresponding to that? Saying *“The salesman had her”* does not mean the same thing.

Comment: In 'BrE', 'to have someone' has the alternative (and earlier I think) meaning 'to dupe someone'. Collins sense 9 has 'usually passive'. 'I nearly had you there' was once very common.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I looked for examples of that which didn't involve *be* but couldn't find any. Any suggestions?

Comment: [PhraseMix](http://www.phrasemix.com/phrases/someone-had-someone-there) gives examples, but I'm not going to vouch for its pedigree. Some padding (not necessarily the 'there') is normal. 'He really had us with his serious delivery – we thought we were in real trouble.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Oh ok, yes thanks: those do sound perfectly normal. Maybe *had me there* or *had me going* somehow make it clearer that somebody's being duped.

Comment: 'Have somebody' has of course evolved rather like 'gay'.